# PyQt5 Close Window on Condition

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I didn't find any answer so I ask this question here. I created 2 simplified files to illustrate my problem. First one is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setFixedSize(196, 134)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 61, 21))
        self.button.setObjectName("Button")

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.action)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button"))

    def action(self):
        condition1 = True
        condition2 = True
        condition3 = True
        if condition1 == True and condition2 == True and condition3 == True:
            # Close the window
            Dialog.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Login()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second file is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from demo import Ui_Login # Importing the UI of the other file


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("Fusion")
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Login()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to close the window by clicking on a button only when some criterias are met (`if  condition1 == True and condition2 == True and condition3 == True:`). If I only run the first file, it perfectly works but when I try by running the second file (which accesses to the first one), I get the error: `line 30, in action Dialog.close() NameError: name 'Dialog' is not defined`

I must launch my app by the second file and not the first one (I forgot to mention that).
How can I fix that? Thank you in advance for you answer!

Comment: @alexpdev I modified my question, I forgot to mention that you had to first launch the login file (here file 2) which access to the signup file (here file 1)

Comment: @alexpdev because it is what seems to be the best to me: 1 file per window (I will have at least 4 different windows)

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I think it now addresses all of your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some adjustments to you original code to accommodate what your goal was as well as make some minor tweaks that better conform to convention and make setup much easier.

Now there is only one entry point from the `login.py` file. If you wanted to open the Signup window as a standalone dialog all you need to do is uncomment the 2 lines at the bottom of the `login.py` file.

Now the signup dialog will not close unless the user either clicks the cancel button or all three of the criteria have been met.

I think there is probably a much better and less error prone way of storing, reading, and editing new users and passwords than storing them in a text file, but maybe that can be a different question if you are interested.

`login.py`

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from signup import SignupDialog
import sys

class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("Login_Dialog")
        self.setFixedSize(196, 134)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        self.username = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 71, 20))
        self.username.setFont(font)
        self.username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")

        self.password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 71, 20))
        self.password.setFont(font)
        self.password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")

        self.username_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.username_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(67, 20, 113, 20))
        self.username_line.setObjectName("username_line")
        self.password_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.password_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(67, 60, 113, 20))
        self.password_line.setObjectName("password_line")
        self.password_line.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)  # To show text as dots

        self.signup_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.signup_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 61, 21))
        self.signup_button.setObjectName("signup_button")

        self.login_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.login_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(85, 100, 91, 21))
        self.login_button.setFont(font)
        self.login_button.setObjectName("login_button")

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)

        self.invalid_username = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.invalid_username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 40, 181, 20))
        self.invalid_username.setPalette(palette)
        self.invalid_username.setText("")
        self.invalid_username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalid_username.setObjectName("invalid_username")

        self.invalid_password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.invalid_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 80, 181, 20))
        self.invalid_password.setPalette(palette)
        self.invalid_password.setText("")
        self.invalid_password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalid_password.setObjectName("invalid_password?")

        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.signup)
        self.login_button.setDefault(True)
        self.username.setFocus()

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login_Dialog", "Login"))
        self.password.setText(_translate("Login_Dialog", "Password"))
        self.username.setText(_translate("Login_Dialog", "Username"))
        self.signup_button.setText(_translate("Login_Dialog", "Sign Up"))
        self.login_button.setText(_translate("Login_Dialog", "Login"))

    def login(self):
        if os.path.exists("accounts.txt"):
            accounts = {}
            with open("accounts.txt", "rt") as a:
                for line in a:
                    if not line.strip(): continue
                    (key, value) = line.split()
                    accounts[key] = value
        username = self.username_line.text()
        password = self.password_line.text()
        # Check if username and password are valid
        if username == "":
            self.invalid_username.setText("Please enter a username")
            return self.invalid_password.setText("")
        if username in accounts.keys():
            self.invalid_username.setText("")
            if password == "":
                return self.invalid_password.setText("Please enter a password")
            if password == accounts[username]:
                self.invalid_password.setText("")
                print("success")
            else:
                return self.invalid_password.setText("Invalid password")
        else:
            return self.invalid_username.setText("Invalid username")

    def showWidget(self):
        self.setHidden(False)

    # Open signup window
    def signup(self):
        self.signupDialog = SignupDialog()
        self.signupDialog.exited.connect(self.showWidget)
        self.signupDialog.show()
        self.setHidden(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    loginDialog = LoginDialog()
    loginDialog.show()    
    # signupDialog = SignupDialog()
    # signupDialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`signup.py`

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SignupDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    exited = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("Signup_Dialog")
        self.setFixedSize(251, 179)
        self.create_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.create_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 140, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.create_button.setFont(font)
        self.create_button.setObjectName("create_button")

        self.cancel_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.cancel_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 91, 21))
        self.cancel_button.setFont(font)
        self.cancel_button.setObjectName("cancel_button")

        self.username = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 101, 20))
        self.username.setFont(font)
        self.username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username.setObjectName("username")

        self.password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 101, 20))
        self.password.setFont(font)
        self.password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.password.setObjectName("password")

        self.confirm_password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.confirm_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 101, 20))
        self.confirm_password.setFont(font)
        self.confirm_password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.confirm_password.setObjectName("confirm_password")

        self.username_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.username_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 121, 20))
        self.username_line.setObjectName("username_line")

        self.password_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.password_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 121, 20))
        self.password_line.setText("")
        self.password_line.setObjectName("password_line")
        self.password_line.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        self.confirm_password_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.confirm_password_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 100, 121, 20))
        self.confirm_password_line.setText("")
        self.confirm_password_line.setObjectName("confirm_password_line")
        self.confirm_password_line.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)

        self.taken_username = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.taken_username.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 35, 121, 20))
        self.taken_username.setPalette(palette)
        self.taken_username.setText("")
        self.taken_username.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.taken_username.setObjectName("taken_username")

        self.invalid_criteria_password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 75, 121, 20))
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setPalette(palette)
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("")
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setObjectName("invalid_criteria_password")

        self.invalid_notsame_password = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 115, 121, 20))
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setPalette(palette)
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setText("")
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setObjectName("invalid_notsame_password")

        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.cancel)
        self.create_button.clicked.connect(self.create)
        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Sign Up"))
        self.create_button.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Create"))
        self.confirm_password.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Confirm Password"))
        self.password.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Create Password"))
        self.username.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Create Username"))
        self.cancel_button.setText(_translate("Signup_Dialog", "Cancel"))

    def cancel(self):
        self.exited.emit()

    def create(self):
        # Create dictionary with usernames and passwords
        accounts = {}
        if os.path.exists("accounts.txt"):
            with open("accounts.txt", "rt") as a:
                for line in a:
                    if not line.strip(): continue
                    (key, value) = line.split()
                    accounts[key] = value
        username = self.username_line.text()
        password = self.password_line.text()
        confirm_password = self.confirm_password_line.text()
        # Check if username is already taken
        if username in accounts:
            self.taken_username.setText("Username already taken")
            return self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("")
        if username == "":
            self.taken_username.setText("Enter a username")
            return self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("")
        self.taken_username.setText("")
        # Check if password is 8-28 characters
        if len(password) < 8:
            return self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("8 characters min")
        if len(password) > 28:
            return self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("28 characters max")
        self.invalid_criteria_password.setText("")
        if password != confirm_password:
            return self.invalid_notsame_password.setText("Confirm your password")
        self.invalid_notsame_password.setText("")
        with open("accounts.txt", "a") as i:
            i.writelines(f"\n{username} {password}")
        self.exited.emit()
        self.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @alexpdev. However, that was not exactly my problem as "accounts.txt" exists (I don't have a FileNotFound Error). The code runs fine, except that I don't know how to close the signup window by clicking on the "Create" button only when the criterias are met.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just have a quick question: why do you put "return ..." in the login function? Does it make any difference or is it just a convention? I'm also going to hash the usernames and password in the accounts file with sha256 so I will compare the hashes when the user logs in. Do you have a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Reywaz  No those returns are necessary... before you had a bunch of nested if statements and boolean flags that you would change from True to False if the criteria were met.  I got rid of that whole system and just force the function to return if any of the conditional statements are True. for instance if the password is less than 8 characters instead of changing the flag and checking the flag at the end it just returns right away

Comment: @Reywaz  In fact both the login and create methods could be optimized further, but I didn't want to make so many changes that it was unrecognizable.

Comment: Thank you, do you also know a way to improve the way of storing, reading, and editing new users and passwords than storing them in a text file? (and do I have to create a new question for it?)

Comment: @Reywaz only if you want to.  I can give you some hints if you want to research yourself though...  for an almost instant switch with very little effort a much easier format to work with is json.  Additionally I would create a data structure attached to your login window so you didn't have to open and close the file every time you need to check a name.  Then just save when an edit has been made.

Comment: I think I won't start coding in json, for now, I will keep what I already have in python. Maybe when my app will be finished I will change my system for a better one, but for now I will just develop my app in python as it is my main project

Comment: @Reywaz  Json isn't a language, its a file structure like plain text, only much easier for working with programs.   But all good.  If you change your mind let me know.  This is a link to the python api for json... its only 4 functions https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html